# QThread pausing when QDialog is hidden

Tags: multithreading, pyqt4

I'm writing a Python plugin for [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (C++ application, with a Python interface for plugins using PyQt4). I'm starting a `QThread` from a `QDialog` using something like the code below, where `Worker` is a `QObject` . This works fine, except that if I hide the `QDialog` before the thread has finished is execution (using the dialog close button) the thread pauses. If I `show()` the dialog again, the thread resumes.

Why is this happening? How can I get the thread to continue running when the dialog is closed?

```
thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
worker = Worker()
worker.moveToThread(thread)
worker.progress.connect(progress.setValue)
thread.started.connect(worker.run)
worker.finished.connect(self.finish)
worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)
thread.start()

self.thread = thread
self.worker = worker
```